# SVG Position difference in Firefox and Chrome should behave the same way?

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to code an SVG, but the placement looks right in Chrome, while the same code looks off in Firefox. Is there any compatibility tag to use to make it look the same?

It looks like the values are interpreted differently in Firefox.

**Code**

```css
body {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<svg
viewbox="0 0 200 200"
style="display: block; width: 100%; position: relative"
>
<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="orange" />
<g
  fill="white"
  font-style="italic"
  transform="translate(25, 90)"
>
  <text
    letter-spacing="-10"
    dx='5'
    dy='0'
  >
    <tspan alignment-baseline="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" font-size="50" font-weight="700">
      +
    </tspan>
    <tspan
      dominant-baseline="middle"
      alignment-baseline="middle"
      font-size="105"
      font-weight="700"
    >
      5
    </tspan>
    <tspan
      dominant-baseline="middle"
      alignment-baseline="middle"
      font-size='45'
      font-weight="700"
      dy="-17"
      dx="20"
    >
      $
    </tspan>
  </text>
  <text dy="60" dx="6" font-size="30" font-weight="700" letter-spacing="1.5">
    DOLLAR
  </text>
</g>
</svg>
```

**Output in Chrome**
[image: chrome]

**Output in Firefox**
[image: firefox]

Comment: You're using a bunch of deprecated arguments such as alignment-baseline and dominant-baseline. I imagine that's the source of the problem.

Comment: Firefox does not support alignment-baseline

Comment: Yep, I checked here and after removing those tags and changing a bit the dy/dx values, it works as expected.

Comment: Just a minor point. dx and dy on a text element are only valid when there is a previous text element to offset from. Chrome incorrectly converts the text element's dx and dy to an x and y value. Firefox correctly ignores them.